# The page div placed at the bottom with with fixed position hides other contents on smaller screen size?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

I have a page where I would like to display a table and a panel that stays at the bottom of the page. I have looked up some answers but none of them works perfectly yet. not sure what is the issue. So the way my current code is to set the parent of the element to be placed at the bottom of the page to relative and set the child content to fixed position with bottom zero. this way it sets the div at the bottom of the page but the problem is that when sizing the page vertically on a smaller size the bottom div hides other page content. How to fix this I am using old bootstrap 3.7.

```html
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>
<body> 
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">
        <div class="table-responsive">
                <table id="" class="table table-striped table-hover table-bordered">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th></th>
                            <th></th>
                            <th></th>
                            <th></th>
                            <th></th>
                            <th></th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td></td>
                            <td></td>
                            <td></td>
                            <td></td>
                            <td></td>
                            <td></td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
            <div class="" style="position:relative;">
                <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12" style="position:fixed; bottom:0;">
                    <div class="panel panel-primary">
                        <div class="panel-heading">
                            <h3 class="panel-title">
                            </h3>
                        </div>
                        <div class="panel-body">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">
                                    <p></p>
                                    <p></p>
                                    <p></p>
                                    <p></p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
         </div>
          </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: you would need to add padding to the bottom of the page equal to the height of the fixed - if that div isn't a set height, you may need to add a bit of js to calculate the amount of padding

Comment: Can you show me how to do that and what is the straightforward way of making a div stick to the bottom of that page while making the div responsive

Comment: the straight forward way would be to duplicate your content at the bottom of the page but have the duplicate set to visibility hidden - that way it would take up the required space without any js.  With js it would be a bit more complicated and you would have o have a go yourself and post another question if you get stuck with anything

Comment: Are you able to update your Bootstrap version? 3 is very old, and newer versions provide flexbox support, which makes this sort of thing effortless.

Answer (score 0):

A snippet with extra padding at the bottom:

```css
.pt-4 {
  padding-top: 16px;
}

.pb-20 {
  padding-bottom: 80px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="container-fluid pt-4 pb-20">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">
      <div class="table-responsive">
        <table id="" class="table table-striped table-hover table-bordered">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th></th>
              <th></th>
              <th></th>
              <th></th>
              <th></th>
              <th></th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td></td>
              <td></td>
              <td></td>
              <td></td>
              <td></td>
              <td></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td></td>
              <td></td>
              <td></td>
              <td></td>
              <td></td>
              <td></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td></td>
              <td></td>
              <td></td>
              <td></td>
              <td></td>
              <td></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td></td>
              <td></td>
              <td></td>
              <td></td>
              <td></td>
              <td></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td></td>
              <td></td>
              <td></td>
              <td></td>
              <td></td>
              <td></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td></td>
              <td></td>
              <td></td>
              <td></td>
              <td></td>
              <td></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td></td>
              <td></td>
              <td></td>
              <td></td>
              <td></td>
              <td></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td></td>
              <td></td>
              <td></td>
              <td></td>
              <td></td>
              <td></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td></td>
              <td></td>
              <td></td>
              <td></td>
              <td></td>
              <td></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td></td>
              <td></td>
              <td></td>
              <td></td>
              <td></td>
              <td></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td></td>
              <td></td>
              <td></td>
              <td></td>
              <td></td>
              <td></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td></td>
              <td></td>
              <td></td>
              <td></td>
              <td></td>
              <td></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td></td>
              <td></td>
              <td></td>
              <td></td>
              <td></td>
              <td></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td></td>
              <td></td>
              <td></td>
              <td></td>
              <td></td>
              <td></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td></td>
              <td></td>
              <td></td>
              <td></td>
              <td></td>
              <td></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td></td>
              <td></td>
              <td></td>
              <td></td>
              <td></td>
              <td></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td></td>
              <td></td>
              <td></td>
              <td></td>
              <td></td>
              <td></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td></td>
              <td></td>
              <td></td>
              <td></td>
              <td></td>
              <td></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td></td>
              <td></td>
              <td></td>
              <td></td>
              <td></td>
              <td></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td></td>
              <td></td>
              <td></td>
              <td></td>
              <td></td>
              <td></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td></td>
              <td></td>
              <td></td>
              <td></td>
              <td></td>
              <td></td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="" style="position:relative;">
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12" style="position:fixed; bottom:0;">
        <div class="panel panel-primary">
          <div class="panel-heading">
            <h3 class="panel-title">
            </h3>
          </div>
          <div class="panel-body">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">
                <p></p>
                <p></p>
                <p></p>
                <p></p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```